# How to fix interlaced mpeg2 video marked as progressive?

Tags: ffmpeg, linux, mpeg

Is there a way to use ffmpeg (or anything else that can be used in linux) to fix an interlaced video marked as progressive, and mark it as interlaced so that I can get rid of bad interlaced frames?

Here's an example of how it is:
[image: Hardly interlaced frame]

And how it should be:
[image: Not interlaced]

Here's the mediainfo of the video:

`Video
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Main@Main
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Custom
Format settings, GOP                     : Variable
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Maximum bit rate                         : 9 800 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Standard                                 : Component
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits`

**`Scan type                                : Progressive`**
`Scan order                               : 2:3 Pulldown
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Time code of first frame                 : 01:00:05:00
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Open
GOP, Open/Closed of first frame          : Closed
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.601
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601`

Do I need a reencode to fix this? Or just change its wrong flag?

Comment: How do you plan to fix it?

Comment: @Gyan I don't know how to fix it. I just have a possible diagnosis. Some forums say the problem lies on the 'progressive' flag. How do I change the flag, then? Do I need to inverse telecine it or something? If so, how do I do it? I couldn't find any solution that actually work anywhere I have searched in. That's why I am asking how to fix it. I tried reencoding it with the `-ilme` option and it just made it worse.

Comment: Did you ever get around this problem? I'd like to know too if there is some way to fix incorrectly marked 'progressive' frames to interlaced without re-encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply. For anyone wondering, the video actually is progressive.  The next line in the mediainfo shows 2:3 pulldown, which is a software added telecine (soft telecine).  You can also see the framerate is 23.976 fps, which should never indicate interlaced video.  This means each frame is progressive, and the video file has flags on the frames so the video player can add telecine during playback so the video is 29.97 fps.  I believe VLC media player ignore the flags completely these days and only shows the progressive frames. You can also use AVISynth to do an inverse telecine with the plugin TIVTC, I suggest making a d2v file with DGIndex from DGMPGDec, but it will be a reencode.  There might also be a way to remove the 2:3 pulldown flag in the metadata, which would remove the telecine without reencoding.